# Angular 6 PWA app not updating after adding to home screen on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, angular6, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I've created an Angular 6 PWA hosted on Firebase.  I'm seeing the correct version of the app in Safari on my iPhone.  However, when I add the app to home screen (make standalone), an older version is getting installed instead.  The home screen app never updates.  I've deleted the app from home screen multiple times and re-installed from Safari and am still getting the older version.  I've even gone so far as to delete all previous versions of the app in Firebase yet the older version of the app keeps getting installed.

What cache is Safari using to install the app on the home screen?  Why is the PWA app itself not updating at all?  Please help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I had to manually 'Clear History and Website Data' for Safari through iPhone's Settings interface which then allowed the latest version to be installed onto the home screen.  This is a manual fix.  What setting has to be made so the auto-update happens when new versions are made available?  You cannot expect users to clear website data every time.

Comment: Any update?????

Comment: I have the same issue :/

Comment: @TomSchreck I have same sort of issue, did you manage to solve it?